# i am not able to load what is on the file in the list of argument in c language why?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void open(FILE *file,...){
    va_list content;
    va_start(content, file);

    vfscanf(file, "%s",content);
    printf("%s",content);

    va_end(content);
};

int main(){
    FILE *file = fopen("test.txt","r");
    open(file);
}
```

i am trying to load what is on the file in the list of arguments but i am not getting any output in the terminal

Comment: You cannot scan into a `va_list` object with `"%s"`; or print a `va_list` object with `"%s"` either.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  You are invoking `open` with only 1 argument; why are you trying to make a variadic function?

Comment: i am new to c  and learning

Comment: Turn on all your compiler warnings - read the documentation for your compiler on how to do that.  Read every warning your compiler puts out and address it - warnings mean the compiler developers think the code that generated the warning is bad, even though it doesn't violate any C standard constraints.  In other words, the people who wrote the compiler put in extra effort to tell you "This code is sketchy. You sure it's right?"  And they built the compiler you're using to turn your code into an executable - you need to listen to them.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear to me what you are trying to do.  Since the format strings and their related arguments are very different for `scanf` than they are for `printf` (eg, "%d" expects an argument of type `int *` in scanf, but printf expects a matching argument of type `int`), it is not likely that you could use the same `va_list` in calls to both `vscanf` and `vprintf`.  For demonstration, maybe you are looking for something like:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>


int
read_file(FILE *fp, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list content;
    va_start(content, fmt);
    int rv = vfscanf(fp, fmt, content);
    va_end(content);
    return rv;
}

int write_file(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    int rv = vprintf(fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    return rv;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int a, b;
    int wc = 0;
    if( (2 == read_file(stdin, "%d%d", &a, &b)) ){
        wc = write_file("%d %d\n", a, b);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input or error\n");
    }
    return !(wc > 0);
}
```

Comment: why const fmt ?????????? it is confusing

Comment: are you trying to write to constant

Comment: The fmt string is not modified by the function.  Using `const` communicates that to the reader.  If the function was attempting to modify the format string, then you would not use the `const` qualifier.